# number of variables in list generic

Tags: c#, list, generics, methods

I want to know which method ( if there is ) in the List<> generic that indicates if the number of objects meets a specific  requirements , example :

```
List<string> example = new List<string>();

if (example."put the method here" = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are no objects in this list");
}
else if (example."put method here" > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This list contains objects");
```

In the example code enough I want to know if this list contains 0 objects , then the console writes a specific text , and if the list contains more than 0 items/objects the console writels another text.

Comment: Please add the language you're using (I'm guessing C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see no of of items in List then just use `Count` (assuming C# is the language). Below is your code looks like:

```
List<string> example = new List<string>();

if (example.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are no objects in this list");
}
else if (example.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This list contains objects");
}
```

If you need to get the items which met specific requirements then use  [Enumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx)

For example if you need the count of all items which starts with string "The" then you can use

```
int count = example.Count(i => i.StartsWith("The") == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Count() == 0 you can use Any() it will save you from typing a few chars! The 'else if' can then be changed to an 'else'.